# How can I make the turtle a random color?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

How can I fix this code to make the turtle a random color? I want to be able to click to make the turtle turn and change color.

```py
import turtle
import random
turtle.colormode(255)
R = 0
G = 0
B = 0
def color(x, y):
    turtle.color((R, G, B))
def turn(x, y):
    turtle.left(10)
for i in range(10000):
    turtle.onscreenclick(turn)
    turtle.forward(1)
    turtle.onrelease(color)
    R = random.randrange(0, 257, 10)
    B = random.randrange(0, 257, 10)
    G = random.randrange(0, 257, 10)
    def color(x, y):
        turtle.color((R, G, B))
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to be able to click then the turtle turns then change color.

I believe this does what you describe:

```
import turtle
import random

def change_color():
    R = random.random()
    B = random.random()
    G = random.random()

    turtle.color(R, G, B)

def turn_and_change_color(x, y):
    turtle.left(10)
    change_color()

turtle.onscreenclick(turn_and_change_color)

def move_forward():
    turtle.forward(1)
    turtle.ontimer(move_forward, 25)

move_forward()

turtle.mainloop()
```

Rather than the `range(10000)` loop, it uses a timer to keep the turtle moving which also allows the event loop to run properly.  It should keep running until you close the turtle window:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle, random


def color(x, y):
    R = random.randrange(0,257,10)
    G = random.randrange(0,257,10)
    B = random.randrange(0,257,10)
    turtle.color(R,G,B)
    turtle.left(10)

turtle.colormode(255)

for i in range(10000):
    turtle.onscreenclick(color)
    turtle.forward(1)
```

Comment: The `turtle.onscreenclick(color)` call only needs to be done **once** before the loop, not every time through the loop.  Also, the color range should be to 256, not 257,  as the color upper limit is 255.